# How to get the sum of rows using a vector and the make the result in a column

Tags: r, row, rowsum

I have a dataframe and i want to calculate the sum of variables present in a vector in every row and make the sum in other variable after i want the name of new variable created to be from the name of the variable in vector

for example

> data

```
Name      A_12    B_12    C_12   D_12    E_12
r1        1         5      12      21     15
r2        2         4       7      10      9
r3        5        15      16       9      6
r4        7         8       0       7     18
```

let's say i have two vectors

```
vector_1 <- c("A_12","B_12","C_12")
vector_2 <- c("B_12","C_12","D_12","E_12")
```

The result i want is :

```
New_data >

 Name        A_12     B_12   C_12   ABC_12     D_12    E_12   BCDE_12
    r1        1         5     12      18         21     15      54
    r2        2         4      7      13         10      9      32
    r3        5        15     16      36          9      6      45
    r4        7         8      0      15          7     18      40
```

I created for loop to get the sum of the rows in a vector but i didn't get the correct result
Please tell me ig you need any more informations or clarifications
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowSums` and simple column-subsetting:

```r
dat$ABC_12 <- rowSums(dat[,vector_1])
dat$BCDE_12 <- rowSums(dat[,vector_2])
dat
#   Name A_12 B_12 C_12 D_12 E_12 ABC_12 BCDE_12
# 1   r1    1    5   12   21   15     18      53
# 2   r2    2    4    7   10    9     13      30
# 3   r3    5   15   16    9    6     36      46
# 4   r4    7    8    0    7   18     15      33
```

Note that if your frames inherit from `data.table`, then you'll need to use either `subset(dat, select=vector_1)` or `dat[,..vector_1]` instead of simply `dat[,vector_1]`; if you aren't already using `data.table`, then you can safely ignore this paragraph.

Comment: thank you for your answer , it works the only problem is that , i don't know the name of vectors because they are generated using for loop so i don't know how to get there names to formulate the name of my variable sum for example i should get the first 3 letters of each variable to formulate the name of new variable : example V1= M11T888 V2=M22T888 , V3=M33T888 the name of new variable should be M112233T888 that's why i need to get the first 3 letters of each element of the vector

Comment: And you think it is okay to *assume* that they all have some common suffix?

Comment: actually , they don't have the same suffix because some of theme have the exacte same name with an extra _2 for example M11T888 and M11T888_2, i just checked my data and knew there's some variables like this

Comment: You're asking for a method to combine unknown column names using a demonstrated-only heuristic (i.e., shared suffix) that is known to be fallible, is that right?

Comment: yes and alsoi don't know the number of vectors because they are generated using for loop

Comment: You've demonstrated creating new names given the sample column names in your question, okay; after that, you state that the real column names look different and defy your presumed heuristic for combining them. After your OP where you ask about sums, you are implicitly expecting us to be able to fix your naming convention when your real data is completely different and yet you do not provide clear examples of these different names. Can you see why this question is stagnant? **Update your question** to better define your naming conundrum. (Lacking that, let's close it as "needs debugging info".)

Comment: Hello , yes, it's better to close it  i will post new question giving more informations and giving also my tries that didn't work thank you

Comment: To confirm, you're saying that question you asked (*"sum of rows"*) is not really your question at all? Or that you asked it, have an answer, and don't need it anymore. The typical method on SO is that you accept one of the acceptable answers and then ask another. My point about closing due to naming-convention issues is to point out that the question does not ask for what you need nor does it give us sufficient info for what you need. If you *needed* the row-of-sums thing and now have a new question, that's different; accept and ask another, please.

Comment: No this it was because, didn't formule my question in a good way for example i said that i gave example of vectors while the vectors are generated using for loop, as you can see , the asnwers used a list of vectors while i don't know the vectors tha t will be genrated, also the name of variables, because it's not the names i want to give to my new variables, and finally because i fixed some bugs in my program so i though it will be better to  ask new question based on  new informations and also itried to give more explications please tell me what the right thing to do in cases like these.

Answer (score 0):

Like this (using `dplyr`/`tidyverse`)

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    ABC_12 = sum(c_across(vector_1)),
    BCDE_12 = sum(c_across(vector_2))
  )
```

Though I'm not sure the sums are correct in your example

-=-=-=EDIT-=-=-=-
Here's a function to help with the naming.

```
ex_fun <- function(vec, n_len){
  paste0(paste(substr(vec,1,n_len), collapse = ""), substr(vec[1],n_len+1,nchar(vec[1])))
}
```

Which can then be implemented like so.

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    !!ex_fun(vector_1, 1) := sum(c_across(vector_1)),
    !!ex_fun(vector_2, 1) := sum(c_across(vector_2)),
  )
```

-=-= Extra note -=--=

If you list your vectors up you could then combine this with r2evans answer and stick into a loop if you prefer.

```
vectors = list(vector_1, vector_2)

for (v in vectors){
  df[ex_fun(v, 1)] <- rowSums(df[,v])
}
```

Comment: Hello , thank you for your answer , it works the only problem is that , i don't know the name of vectors because they are generated using for loop so i don't know how to get there names to formulate the name of my variable sum  for example i should get the first 3 letters of each variable to formulate the name of new variable : example V1= M11T888 V2=M22T888 , V3=M33T888 the name of new variable should be M112233T888 that's why i need to get the first 3 letters of each element of the vector

Comment: Edit added, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might work, so long as only the starting digits are different:

```
library("tidyverse")

#Input dataframe.
data <- data.frame(Name =c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4"), A_12 = c(1, 2, 5, 7), B_12 = c(5, 4, 15, 8),
           C_12 = c(12, 7, 16, 0), D_12 = c(21, 10, 9, 7), E_12 = c(15, 9, 6, 18))

#add all vectors to the "vectors" list. I have added vector_1 and vector_2, but
#there can be as many vectors as needed, they just need to be put in the list.
vector_1 <- c("A_12","B_12","C_12")
vector_2 <- c("B_12","C_12","D_12","E_12")

vector_list<-list(vector_1, vector_2)

vector_sum <- function(data, vector_list){
  output <- data |>
    dplyr::select(1, all_of(vector_list[[1]]))
  
  for (i in vector_list) {
    name1 <- substring(as.character(i), 1,1) |> paste(collapse = '')
    name2 <- substring(as.character(i[1]), 2)
    
    input_temp <- dplyr::select(data, all_of(i))
    input_temp <- mutate(input_temp, temp=rowSums(input_temp))
    names(input_temp)[names(input_temp) == "temp"] <- paste(name1, name2)
    
    output = cbind(output, input_temp)
  }
  
  output[, !duplicated(colnames(output))]
}


vector_sum(data, vector_list)
```